# Number to Word Conversion and Display result in Abacus - Java

Tags: java

This is regarding an Assignment in my University Program. I'm to create a program that converts the Valid Number into Words and Displays the Result also in Abacus way.

Example :- 899 ( Eight Hundred and Ninety Nine ).

I have a sample code that I have designed but I know its wrong and bit buggy. And we are to use basic commands and if statements.

I want to create a program that Prompts user to enter Number (Between 0 - 900) 
and validates it,

And the number must be displayed in Words and also in Abacus way.`

Below is the sample code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Welcome to my maths app");
    System.out.print("Input number between one and nine hundred"); 
    while (!studentInput.hasNextInt())
        int number = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    {
        System.out.println("Your input does not match the criteria, please enter a number between 1 and 900");
        numberInput.next();

        while ( number > 1 || number < 900) {
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire code and wrap it all in code block? 
while ( number > 1 || number < 900) 
I think that was supposed to be: while ( number > 1 && number < 900), or 
while ( number < 1 || number > 900)

Comment: How do I wrap the entire code in code block? I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: First, you post the entire code, which you haven't done yet, then you select the entire code with your mouse, and click the 'code block' [ {} ] button.

Comment: There is no entire code with me. I only did up to the part I have finished in the above code. I can't think how to finish the whole code. Please help me.

Comment: So: basically your question is: write my code for me?

Comment: You, sir, deserve a stern beating for your terrible code formatting ;) I tried to fix it. If you had formatted your code correctly in the first place, you'd see your mistake right away.

Also, please don't ask other people to do your work. This is YOUR homework, so YOU do it. This is a very easy task. If you can't do that on your own and/or with the help of Google, maybe rethink your choice of profession.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to complete my code for me. Just tell me what I'm missing and I like to know how to do it. Because I have never done numbers to text and in abacus problems before.